# Using Cell Fracture to create a stone wall

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, add-on

I have been using Cell Fracture to create a stone wall to be 3d printed.
My first attempt went well:

[image]

But my second attempt hasn't, it has ended up as the following abomination. Could someone help me find out where I have gone wrong? Here is my process:

1. Create wall shape (1cmx10cmx2xcm in metric)
2. Insert Particle modifier with an emission number of 1000
3. Execute Cell Fracture with the following settings in the third picture
4. Subsurface Division with default values
5. Copy using "copy attributes menu" add-on
6. Select all and use shrink/fatten to stretch the 'rocks' to the right size

If anyone can spot where I have gone wrong that would be absolutely perfect.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

I have tried using own verts instead of own particles. The issue i am now facing is that the fractures do not fill the entire mesh as shown below. I am truly stumped on what to do as no matter what setting I change, It still has massive gaps.
[image]

Comment: From what I have tested it appears that it is to do with the scale. I now do the object in 1/10th scale and then fracture it. Once that is done I scale it up by a factor of 10.